# How to get cljsbuild to run BEFORE uberjar compiles a clojure app?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, isomorphic-javascript

I'm making an isomorphic app in clojure / clojurescript / reagennt. Due to the fact that I have a dependency on a clojurescript output js file for server-side rendering, I'd like that file to be compiled before the jar does. How do I do that?

Here's the output of "lein uberjar" notice the jar is compiled first. My clj file "nash.clj" needs to run the compiled server-side.js build:

```
Johns-MacBook-Pro:bfa-clojure johnkealy$ lein uberjar

minifying assets...

minifying: resources/public/css/site.min.css
assets: site.css
original size: 88983
compressed size: 73886
gzipped size: 13676
Compiling bfa-clojure.api.auth
Compiling bfa-clojure.api.misc
Compiling bfa-clojure.api.photos
Compiling bfa-clojure.global
Compiling bfa-clojure.handler
Compiling bfa-clojure.nash
Compiling bfa-clojure.pages
Compiling bfa-clojure.server
2015-08-17 14:34:32.964:INFO::main: Logging initialized @21242ms
Compiling ClojureScript.
Compiling "resources/public/javascripts/server-side.js" from ("src/cljs" "src/server-cljs" "src/clj/bfa_clojure/queries" "src/cljs" "src/server-cljs" "src/clj/bfa_clojure/queries")...
Successfully compiled "resources/public/javascripts/server-side.js" in 7.441 seconds.
```

And my project.clj...the whole cljsbuild thing is currently a mystery to me.

```
(defproject bfa-clojure "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}

  :source-paths ["src/clj" "src/cljs"]

  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                 [ring-server "0.4.0"]
                 [cljsjs/react "0.13.3-1"]
                 [reagent "0.5.0"]
                 [reagent-forms "0.5.4"]
                 [reagent-utils "0.1.5"]
                 [ring "1.4.0"]
                 [cider/cider-nrepl "0.7.0"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.3"]
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.1.5"]
                 [prone "0.8.2"]
                 [cheshire "5.3.1"]
                 [fogus/ring-edn "0.3.0"]
                 [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6"]
                 [com.cemerick/url "0.1.1"]
                 [org.clojure/core.async "0.1.267.0-0d7780-alpha"]
                 [clj-http "2.0.0"]
                 [compojure "1.4.0"]
                 [cljs-ajax "0.3.13"]
                 [hiccup "1.0.5"]
                 [environ "1.0.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-3308" :scope "provided"]
                 [mori "0.2.4"]
                 [secretary "1.2.3"]]

  :less {:source-paths ["src/less"]
           :target-path "resources/public/css"}

  :plugins [[lein-less "1.7.5"]
            [lein-environ "1.0.0"]
            [lein-asset-minifier "0.2.2"]]

  :ring {:handler bfa-clojure.handler/app
         :uberwar-name "bfa-clojure.war"}

  :min-lein-version "2.5.0"

  :uberjar-name "bfa-clojure.jar"

  :main bfa-clojure.server

  :clean-targets ^{:protect false} [:target-path
                                    [:cljsbuild :builds :app :compiler :output-dir]
                                    [:cljsbuild :builds :app :compiler :output-to]]

  :minify-assets
  {:assets
    {"resources/public/css/site.min.css" "resources/public/css/site.css"}}

  :cljsbuild {:builds {:app {:source-paths ["src/cljs" "src/client-cljs" "src/clj/bfa_clojure/queries"]
                             :compiler {:output-to     "resources/public/js/app.js"
                                        :output-dir    "resources/public/js/out"
                                        :asset-path   "/js/out"
                                        :optimizations :none
                                        :pretty-print  true}}}}

  :profiles {:dev {:repl-options {:init-ns bfa-clojure.repl
                                  :nrepl-middleware []}

                   :dependencies [[ring-mock "0.1.5"]
                                  [ring/ring-devel "1.4.0"]
                                  [lein-figwheel "0.3.7"]
                                  [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.10"]
                                  [pjstadig/humane-test-output "0.7.0"]]

                   :source-paths ["env/dev/clj"]
                   :plugins [[lein-figwheel "0.3.7"]
                             [lein-cljsbuild "1.0.6"]]

                   :injections [(require 'pjstadig.humane-test-output)
                                (pjstadig.humane-test-output/activate!)]

                   :figwheel {:http-server-root "public"
                              :server-port 3449
                              :nrepl-port 7002
                              :css-dirs ["resources/public/css"]
                              :ring-handler bfa-clojure.handler/app}

                   :env {:dev true}

                   :cljsbuild {:builds {:app {:source-paths ["env/dev/cljs"]
                                              :compiler {:main "bfa-clojure.dev"
                                                         :source-map true}}
                                        :server {:id "server-side"
                                                 :source-paths ["src/cljs" "src/server-cljs" "src/clj/bfa_clojure/queries"]
                                                 :compiler {:output-to "resources/public/javascripts/server-side.js"
                                                            :output-dir "resources/public/javascripts/out-server-side"
                                                            :preamble ["underscore-min.js"]
                                                            :pretty-print false
                                                            :warnings true
                                                            :optimizations :whitespace}}}}}

             :uberjar {:hooks [leiningen.cljsbuild minify-assets.plugin/hooks]
                       :env {:production true}
                       :aot :all
                       :omit-source true
                       :cljsbuild {:jar true
                                   :main "bfa-clojure.core"
                                   :builds {
                                            :server {:id "server-side"
                                                     :source-paths ["src/cljs" "src/server-cljs" "src/clj/bfa_clojure/queries"]
                                                     :compiler {:output-to "resources/public/javascripts/server-side.js"
                                                                :output-dir "resources/public/javascripts/out-server-side"
                                                                :preamble ["underscore-min.js"]
                                                                :pretty-print false
                                                                :warnings true
                                                                :optimizations :whitespace}}

                                            :app
                                            {:source-paths ["env/prod/cljs"]
                                             :externs ["underscore-min.js"]
                                             :compiler
                                             {:optimizations :advanced
                                              :externs ["underscore-min.js"]
                                              :pretty-print false}}}}}})
```

Comment: I just edited my answer. Hope it helps. What's your specific issue with the build? Are the js files being generated under "resources/public/javascripts"? Are they being included in the uberjar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the [cljsbuild hooks](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild#hooks) in your project.clj:

```
:hooks [leiningen.cljsbuild]
```

About your `lein uberjar` output, you say:

> notice the jar is compiled first

That's not what's happening. I see output from the following tasks, in order:
- lein minify (or whatever is named the task which minifies the css)
- lein compile
- lein cljsbuild once

We can't say from the output if the jar task has run before or after those tasks, but that's how it works: by default, uberjar runs `clean` -> `javac` -> `compile` -> `jar`

The hook makes cljsbuild to run after the `compile` task. That's why you see "Compiling bfa-clojure.api.auth..." before "Compile ClojureScript"

Comment: I have that, but it still builds the jar before the cljs compiles

Comment: @jdkealy could you please share your `project.clj` file, and any other information you consider relevant, like the exact command you are executing, or how are you arriving to the conclusion that the jar is built before the cljs compiles?

Comment: Of course, please remove or redact any sensitive information from project.clj